# If $X \subset Y \subset Z$ are Metric Spaces with the same metric, is $\overline{X}$ the same be it taken in relation to $Y$ or $Z$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $X \subset Y \subset Z$ are Metric Spaces, if $d_Z(\cdot,\cdot):Z \times Z \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ is the metric of $Z$, $d_Y(\cdot,\cdot):=d_Z(\cdot,\cdot)\restriction_{Y\times Y}$ is the metric of $Y$ and $d_X(\cdot,\cdot):=d_Z(\cdot,\cdot)\restriction_{X\times X}$ the metric of $X$ are the following sets the same ?

$$\overline{X}_Y := \{y\in Y\, | \,\,d_Y(y,X) =0 \} \,;\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ d_Y(y,X) := \inf_{y' \in Y}d_Y(y,y')$$

$$\overline{X}_Z := \{z\in Z\, | \,\,d_Z(z,X) =0 \} \,;\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ d_Z(z,X) := \inf_{z' \in Z}d_Y(z,z')$$

That is $\overline{X}_Y = \overline{X}_Z\,?$ If so can this be generalised for when $X,Y$ and $Z$ are topological spaces and the closure of $X$ being defined by the topological closure ?( i belive it to be something like the intersection of all closed sets in relation to $K= Y$ or $Z$ that contain $X$).

Comment: What if $Y=X$ and $X$ is not closed in $Z$?  (e.g. $X = Y = (0,1)$, $Z = \mathbb{R}$)

Comment: $\overline{X}_Y = Y\cap \overline{X}_Z$

Comment: @DanielSchepler I belive that in the case $X = Y ,  \overline{X}_Y = X $, therefore perhaps i should put proper inclusion, but $X$ doesn't need to be closed in Z, that is the hole point.

Comment: The two are the same if $Y$ is a closed subset of $Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the point-set way to get to the right conclusion.  If you want to do it in metrics, everything is still true.  First prove the following:

**Lemma:**  Let $A$ be a subset of a space $Z$ and give $A$ the corresponding subspace topology. Prove that a set $C$ is closed in the *subspace topology* on $A$ if and only if $C = A \cap K$ for some set $K$ closed in $Z$.

With that it's not hard to prove the following, which is the answer to your question:

**Proposition:**  Suppose we have a chain $X \subseteq Y \subseteq Z$ where $Z$ is a topological space.  Write $\overline{X}_Z$ for the closure of $X$ in the space $Z$ and $\overline{X}_Y$ for the closure of $X$ in the subspace topology on $Y$ inherited from $Z$.  Then $\overline{X}_Y = Y \cap \overline{X}_Z$.

From this, you get that $\overline{X}_Y = \overline{X}_Z$ if $Y$ is a closed set in $Z$.

Answer (score 0):

I belive i have come to the conclusion that if i take $Y=X\ \cup \{y\}$ such that $y\not\in X$ and $d_Y(y,X) = 0$ then $\overline{X}_Y = Y$  and if $Z=Y \ \cup \{z\}$ such that $z\not\in Y$ and $d_Z(z,X)=0$ then $\overline{X}_Z = Z$. So it is false.